# Hiding iframe id after page reload using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have one query regarding hiding iframe id after page reload using jQuery.
I have one external live chat (which uses the following iframe )

```
<iframe id="customer-chat-iframe" name="mcs_1380166852448_" src="https://testlivechat.test.com/php/app.php?widget-iframe-content" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style="background: transparent; border: none; outline: none; position: fixed; display: block; z-index: 999999; bottom: -355px; right: 30px; overflow: hidden; min-width: 279px; min-height: 368px; width: 340px; height: 400px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"></iframe>
```

The live chat is getting called in an external website.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//testlivechat.test.com/php/app.php?widget-init.js"></script>
```

My requirement is that i need to hide the chat box initially (after entire page reload), then upon clicking some specific event like button click, the chat box should display..

I tried the same with jquery, but unable to hide initially.

NOT WORKING CODE:

```
(function( $ ) { 
 $('#customer-chat-iframe').hide(); 
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using JS Cookie:

```
/** This is load on page ready. **/
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var isCookieSet = getCookie("c_chat"); 
  if(isCookieSet == "" || isCookieSet == null){
    $('#customer-chat-iframe').css("display", "none");
  }
  else{
    $('#customer-chat-iframe').css("display", "block");
  }
});


/*Function to get cookie value **/
function getCookie(c_name) {
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    if (c_start != -1) {
        c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
        c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1) {
            c_end = document.cookie.length;
        }
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
  }
  return "";
}




/** This will execute on click of radio button and set the cookie **/
function onRadioButtonClicked(){
  var isCookieSet = getCookie("c_chat"); 
  if(isCookieSet == "" || isCookieSet == null){
    document.cookie = "c_chat=1";
  }
  $('#customer-chat-iframe').css("display", "block");
}
```

You need to call "onRadioButtonClicked()" on your radio button .
Let me know if this works for you

Comment: @DeepeshKumar Can you put this code inside Chrome Inspector and let me know if it works..



     $('#customer-chat-iframe').css("display", "none");

Comment: Yes it works in chrome inspector, i tried and got the following result:
=========
jQuery('#customer-chat-iframe').css("display", "none");
[iframe#customer-chat-iframe, context: document, selector: "#customer-chat-iframe"]
=========

Comment: So basically code work but somehow it is not working when you refresh the page..
Try placing this code at the end of the body tag.

Comment: when i looked at view page source, i can see that the code i am placing is at the end of the body tag...

Comment: Try this:-         


window.setInterval(function(){
       $('#customer-chat-iframe').css("display", "none");
    }, 3000);

It will execute after 3 sec when page is finished loading (3000ms = 3sec).

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Wow.. that worked.... but i dont want to display that even for 3 secs..

Comment: Then may be try putting 1000ms or even less (if it works perfectly)..
Pls mark my as answer as solution for your question.. :)

Comment: But anyway user will see this, even for 1sec. I dont want to do that.
Also when i refresh the page, again it is hiding. I need to set a session for this, means once checked the radio button, that chat should be visible, even if we refresh the page. So how can i achieve this Shashank

Comment: @DeepeshKumar I have updated my answer and now I am using cookie. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hello Shashank, do i need to remove the  code window.setInterval(function(){ $('#customer-chat-iframe').css("display", "none"); }, 3000);  before adding your code ?

Comment: I don't think it is required..but try both ways..hope it works :)

Comment: Hai shashank, i have added the code, but upon refreshing the page, again the chat is hidden. Please have a look at my requirement: 
Initially user checked one radio button, then chat box should display.
Then after refreshing the page/going to another page, the chat should display.. The chat should close only after switiching to another radio button(which contains some contact form popup)

Comment: can you post your whole code somewhere and then tell me where it is going wrong.

Comment: Shashank, i have changed as per your code..But cookie is not working.. Is there any mistake in my code? if yes please let me know.. upon page refresh, again the chat box is hiding.

Comment: Hai shashank.. can you please help me ? have you checked?
Also when using setInterval, i need the chat box to be hidden without any delay on page reload. So I gave zero(delay) as setInterval parameter. But somehow it is showing (for millisecs) then it is getting disappeared. This is not user friendly. Can you help me to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Hello Shashank, I have updated my code like this. When I clicked on live chat radio button, the url will get loaded (used getScript function), but the issue is that upon clicking radio button, there will be delay(around 3,4 seconds ) between hiding the winodow containing radio button and showing live chat box. Do you have any idea to reduce the time delay?

Comment: In your main css file, add something like this:

iframe{ display : none}; 

So initially it will be hidden always. When client selects raido button, execute my code which sets cookie and then this iframe would be visible(because we are setting display : block). 

So even if client switches to next page , then also it would be hidden initially , but would show after a sec. 

Else it would be hidden always..
Let me know if it works..